# What is the minimum error achievable using gaussian process emulation?

Tags: numerics, error-estimation, statistics, approximation, gaussian-process

I am interested in using Gaussian processes as emulators for other computational models, and I would like to characterize the expected numerical precision of the emulator.
Specifically, how small can $|\hat{y}_{\mathrm{emulator}} - y_{\mathrm{model}}|$ be made given the limitations of floating point computation. Secondarily, how do these depend on the kernel choice and optimization method?

Beyond this are any articles or other resources that focus on the numerical aspects of Gaussian processes for noiseless data or how the errors in numerical computations contribute to the statistical properties? As Gaussian processes are mostly used in a statistical setting, I have not seen this discussed much.

In this context the data, $y_{\mathrm{model}} = f(X)$, has no stochastic part, so errors or perturbations are only due to floating point arithmetic or for more complex models the combined effects of iteration and approximation error.

Naively the prediction process depends on the condition numbers, $\kappa$, of the covariance matrices  $K(X', X)$ and $K(X, X)$ resulting from the kernel $K(\cdot, \cdot)$. The prediction is given by
$$
\hat{y}' = K(X', X) K(X, X)^{-1} y
$$
where $X$ and $y$ are the training data, and $X'$ are the values for which $\hat{y}'$ is predicted.

So if the kernel hyper parameters are known exactly and evaluated exactly one expects a relative error of
$\kappa(K(X', X))\kappa(K(X, X)) \epsilon_\mathrm{model}$, where $\epsilon_\mathrm{model}$ is the numerical error due to solving the computational model that will be emulated.

In practice the evaluation of the kernel introduces errors into the matrices $K(X', X)$ and $K(X, X)$, and these additionally are inexact as the values of the kernel hyper parameters are numerically optimized. Consequently, taking the condition number of the evaluated $K(X', X)$ and $K(X, X)$ is not sufficient to fully characterize the approximation error. Are there any bounds that account for the additional errors due to this?

Comment: As Gaussian process emulation (or Kriging) is basically scattered data interpolation using a radial basis function, I'd expect the amount of training data and locations $X$ to have a much larger impact than general floating point errors. However, locations $X$ and the condition number are antagonists: Increasing fill distance diminishes approximation error but increase condition number: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02432002